# Limit form submission rate

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cookies, limit

On my new site I want to cut spam by limiting users to a maximum of 2 posts per hour (this may change to allow more but for now its 2) I devised a method for this using cookies, however, for some reason the site isn't setting the cookie, here's my code for the cookies:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mysql_table (timestamp,entry,uid,allowcomments) VALUES ('$timestamp','$entry','".rndTxt(16)."','$allowcommenting')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't insert into table.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

   if ($result != false) {

        if(isset($_COOKIE['AnonPost']))
        {
        $hour = time() + 3600; 
        setcookie("AnonPost", "2", $hour); 
        }

        else {
        $hour = time() + 3600; 
        setcookie("AnonPost", "1", $hour); 
        }

        print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=index.php'>";
    }

     mysql_close();
```

And then a later if/else statement checks to see if it exists, and what the value is (if it doesn't exist they see the site as normal, if it does and the val=1 then it displays a message saying only one post left, and if the val=2 they get a message saying they've run out of posts this hour.)

This works on my localhost, but not on the site itself (http://aviatex14.co.uk/anonpost/ ) any idea's why?

Aside from that, I'm aware that this is not the best way to limit the posts, so, can anyone help me with limiting the form submission, or advise me on my cookie problem?

Comment: You may want to look into better ways to handle spam. Limiting posts per hour will hinder real users more than spammers.

Comment: Also, cookies can easily be deleted.

Comment: Hmmm, that had occurred to me, but this is a temporary whilst we sort the bigger stuff out. I wonder, do you think php sessions that limit it to more like you have to wait 60/120 seconds after each post before you can post again would work? It's more to stop human spammers posting continuously

Comment: how do you know they are humans and not bots?

Comment: I have a system to stop bots in place already, those that break through the filter can be dealt with separately, however humans can complete the anti spam, and then post, and can continue to do so. That's what I need to limit.

Comment: @Aviate: bots can just dump cookies and would get a new clean session each time. The only way to limit properly is by IP (which hurts users being corporate/ISP nat gateways) and via CAPTCHAs.

Comment: Bots agent my problem, its people choosing to continuously post

Comment: "I have a system to stop bots in place already" - what system is that? if it's not a captcha, then it's not going to stop them, and even bots can break through some captchas. it would be *extremely* rare that real actual people would sit around continuously spamming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reduce spam there are many methods

A captcha system. http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Email confirmation during account creation.

Spam recognition during post. Looks for spammy keywords.

Honeypot fields in forms. This uses CSS to hide a honeypot input field on each form. If the request comes to the server with that field filled in, you know a bot submitted the form and can ignore the request.

Reputation system like the one on stack exchange. You only give users permission to do certain things once they have built up a certain amount of repution.

Comment: Awesome post, i'd add that the honey pot should be something out of the $_SESSION array that is random so bots can't just fire vars to the $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

Consideration 1: in order to set a cookie, it needs to be done before ANY HTML is sent to the page (so it's got to be right at the top of your script, along with session_start).

Consideration 2: speaking of session_start, you might want to consider setting a $_SESSION variable, rather than setting a cookie.

- they're easier to use and deal with
- the user can't modify them, aside from destroying the php session cookie (but then they're going to log back in, and you can check again at that point)
- you can set/modify/remove them at any point after starting the session, rather than remembering to set a cookie before any call to "print" "printf" or "echo"
- you're lowering your header-bandwidth - always a good thing

Comment: Doesn't necessarily have to be at the top of the script, just as you said, before the body of the response. You can use output buffering to allow cookies and other headers to be set anywhere (although this should be avoided if possible for performance reason).

Comment: Absolutely.  I don't want to make it sound like it's the first thing that needs to be done, however, all too often, it's the culprit that somebody thinks they have time, and 4 includes in, there's a print or an echo somewhere.  And buffering would work, but that's a big jump for a little task.

Comment: hehehe, very true. I've certainly been burned by that one before :)

Answer (score 1):

Using cookie (because it is stored on client side) is not a safe way to set a limitation. The user will be able to change it easily so you should try a server side method.

Here you can simply count a user's posts from your database. Something like this will give you number of posts of a user in the last hour :

```
select count(*) from mysql_table where uid='$uid' and timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR););
```